# Bootstrap gradient with 4 colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, linear-gradients

I have used 4 colors to create css gradient its like this.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 72%,#929292 72%,#929292 100%);
```

Here I am using bootstrap. my problem is how I call this kind of gradient in my less file?

If it has 2 or 3 colors in gradients it is okay for me. Then I can use bootstrap mixin funciton like this..

```
#gradient.vertical(#ffffff; #f9f9f9 );
#gradient.vertical-three-colors(#ffffff; #f9f9f9; 72%; #e7eaef);
```

but I am not sure how to use it with over 3 colors..

hope someone may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: store it in a variable?

Comment: @Harry I am really not sure how to store like this values in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your own four way gradient mixin and add it to bootstrap/less/mixins/grandients.less

Such as:

```
  .horizontal-four-colors(@start-color: #00b3ee; @mid-color: #7a43b6; @color-stop: 33%; @mid-color-2: #abcdef; @color-stop-2: 66%; @end-color: #c3325f) {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @start-color, @mid-color @color-stop, @mid-color-2 @color-stop-2, @end-color);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @start-color, @mid-color @color-stop, @mid-color-2 @color-stop-2,@end-color);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @start-color, @mid-color @color-stop, @mid-color-2 @color-stop-2, @end-color);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=1)",argb(@start-color),argb(@end-color))); // IE9 and down, gets no color-stop at all for proper fallback
  }
```

and call it with

```
#gradient.horizontal-four-colors(#ffffff; #f9f9f9; 33%; #bbb, 66%, #e7eaef);
```